# delete selected row of table from database in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

I want to delete the selected row from MySql Database when Click on delete button in my shinyapp. The codes of ui.r and server.r are as following:
It is connected to MySQl and I can save data to mySQL but I cannot delete and Update the table.
1: connection to database

```
 # Define the fields we want to save from the form
     fields <- c("name", "used_shiny", "r_num_years")
    #connect to MySQL

    options(mysql = list(
      "host" = "127.0.0.1",
      "port" = 3306,
      "user" = "root",
      "password" = ""
      ))
    databaseName <- "myshinydatabase"
     table <- "responses"
     saveData <- function(data) {
       # Connect to the database
       db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host = options()$mysql$host, 
               port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
              password = options()$mysql$password)
```

Function of delete Data :

```
deleteData <- function() {
    # Connect to the database
     db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host = options()$mysql$host, 
                         port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
                         password = options()$mysql$password)
      # Construct the deleting query
      query <- sprintf("DELETE selctedrow FROM %s", table)
     # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
      data <- dbGetQuery(db, query)
     dbDisconnect(db)
      data
  }
```

When Delete button is clicked, delete the selected row of data

```
observeEvent(input$delete.button, {
    deleteData (formData())
  })
```

The code for ui.r

```
ui <- fluidPage(
      #use shiny js to disable the ID field
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
      #DT::dataTableOutput("responses"),
      shinyjs::disabled(textInput("id", "Id", "0")),

      textInput("name", "Name", ""),
      checkboxInput("used_shiny", "I've built a Shiny app in R before", FALSE),
      sliderInput("r_num_years", "Number of years using R", 0, 25, 2, ticks = FALSE),

      actionButton("submit", "Submit",icon = icon("plus-circle"),class = "btn-primary"),
      # Delete button 
      actionButton(inputId = "delete", label = "Delete", icon = icon("minus-circle"),class = "btn-primary"),
      #NEW button
      actionButton("new", "Reset",icon = icon("refresh"),class = "btn-primary")
    ))
    ,box(
      title = "KPIs", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
      collapsible = TRUE,
     DT::dataTableOutput("responses"), tags$hr()

    )),
```

The Error message that I get:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5894
Warning: Unhandled error in observer: unused argument (formData())
observeEvent(input$delete.button)
```

Comment: my problem is in deleteData(),  DELETE command in query, as I do not know how I can write a query to delete only selected row?any suggestion please

Comment: First, `DELETE * FROM` table is not correct MySQL syntax. It does not use the asterisk. Second, just pass the form data' id or name field as parameter to function to run: `DELETE FROM table WHERE id=idparam`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I say that where id=selectedid.can you please tell me the format of sql in rmysql it seems that it is different from normal sql.

Comment: How can I write a method to get the selectedid and pass it into the method of above?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the current form's id parameter into the function. Then concatenate the id into the `WHERE` clause of the [DELETE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/delete.php) query. By the way the `DELETE` statement does not take any field as it removes the entire row and not one particular column.

UI side

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  #use shiny js to disable the ID field
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  #DT::dataTableOutput("responses"),
  shinyjs::disabled(textInput("id", "Id", "0")),

  selectInput("ID", 
              label = "Choose ID from list",
              choices = c(1:50), 
              selected = "1"),   

  textOutput("successtext"),

  textInput("name", "Name", ""),
  checkboxInput("used_shiny", "I've built a Shiny app in R before", FALSE),
  sliderInput("r_num_years", "Number of years using R", 0, 25, 2, ticks = FALSE),

  actionButton("submit", "Submit",icon = icon("plus-circle"),class = "btn-primary"),
  # Delete button 
  actionButton(inputId = "delete", label = "Delete", icon = icon("minus-circle"),class = "btn-primary"),
  #NEW button
  actionButton("new", "Reset",icon = icon("refresh"),class = "btn-primary")
))
,box(
  title = "KPIs", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
  collapsible = TRUE,
 DT::dataTableOutput("responses"), tags$hr()

)),
```

Server side

```
observeEvent(input$delete.button, {
     deleteData(input$ID)         
})

deleteData <- function(formid) {
     # Connect to the database
     db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = databaseName, host = options()$mysql$host, 
                         port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
                         password = options()$mysql$password)

     # Construct the deleting query
     query <- sprintf("DELETE FROM %s WHERE id = %d", table, formid)

     # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
     rs <- try(dbSendQuery(db, query))
     if(inherits(rs, ErrorClass)){ 
               output$successtext <- renderText({paste0("Failed to remove ID ", 
                          input$ID, " from database table. Please contact administrator.")})
               } 
     } else {
               output$successtext <- renderText({paste0("Successfully removed ID ", 
                          input$ID, " from database table!")})
               } 
     }
     dbDisconnect(db)
}
```

Also, be sure to sanitize and validate the form data especially id field. `DELETE` is a very powerful function and [sql injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) is always an issue when an application receives user inputted data.

Comment: How can I get the formid by clicking on the table?

Comment: You might need to use an input field or dropdown. Then, have user select an id to remove and click button to process (i.e., send id to function)

Comment: I have updated my code, I have 4 inputs. how can I choose the selected id ?can you please write me a simple example?

Comment: I add a dropdown for selecting IDs (1-50) and then delete button calls `deletedata()` function, passing the `input$ID` to run in query and an output success text renders. Play around with it.